# Ionic 5 - I need to detect changes to an array after passing from a child page to the parent

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a parent component and by means of a query get to a REST API to save it in an array, then all that data is loaded in a list, so far everything is fine, the problem is when I go to a child route to display the information of a specific data, when I make the modification or removal of an item from the array and return to the previous path, the list is not updated and I have to do a refresh manually to see the changes, use an **ion-refresher-content** to do it from the same app but it is not what I need, I want it as soon as the application redirects me, it automatically detects the changes and makes a get request and reloads the list.

The code of my parent page:

```
export class ListaEnsayosPage implements OnInit {
      ensayos:Ensayo[];
      titulo:string="Lista de Ensayos";

      constructor(private ensayoService:EnsayoService) {
       };

      ngOnInit() {
        this.ensayoService.getAll().subscribe(data=>{
          this.ensayos=data['data'];
        });
      };
      doRefresh(event) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.ensayoService.getAll().subscribe(data=>{
            this.ensayos=data['data'];
          });
          event.target.complete();
        }, 1500);
      }
    }
```

the code of my child page:

```
export class EnsayoPage implements OnInit {
          titulo:string="Info ensayo";
          ensayo:Ensayo={
            operador:"",
            distanciaTotal:null,
            radioTrayectoria:null,
            materialBola:"",
            carga:null,
            diametroBola:null,
            codigoProbeta:"",
            durezaProbeta:null,
            tratamientoProbeta:"",
            materialProbeta:"",
            observaciones:"",
          };;

          constructor(private activeRoute:ActivatedRoute, private ensayoService:EnsayoService) {

           }

          ngOnInit() {
            this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(params=>{
              this.ensayo.idEnsayo=params['idEnsayo'];
            });
            if(this.ensayo.idEnsayo){
              this.ensayoService.getOne(this.ensayo.idEnsayo).subscribe(data=>{
                this.ensayo=data['data'];
              });
            };
          }

        }
```

And this is the component of the form that does the modification (for reasons of recycling code, separate the form into a component)

```
formularioEnsayo: FormGroup;
          @Input() ensayo: Ensayo;
          constructor(private ensayoService:EnsayoService, private router:Router) { 
            this.formularioEnsayo = new FormGroup({
              'operador': new FormControl('',Validators.required),
              'observaciones': new FormControl(),
              'idEnsayo': new FormControl(),
              'fecha': new FormControl(),
              'tiempoTotal': new FormControl(),
              'distanciaTotal': new FormControl('',Validators.required),
              'radioTrayectoria': new FormControl('',Validators.required),
              'materialBola': new FormControl('',Validators.required),
              'carga': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
              'diametroBola': new FormControl('',Validators.required),
              'codigoProbeta': new FormControl('',Validators.required),
              'durezaProbeta': new FormControl('',Validators.required),
              'tratamientoProbeta': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
              'materialProbeta': new FormControl('',Validators.required)
            });

          }

          ngOnInit() {
            if(this.ensayo.idEnsayo){
              this.ensayoService.getOne(this.ensayo.idEnsayo).subscribe(async data=>{
                this.ensayo=data['data'];
                await this.formularioEnsayo.setValue(this.ensayo);
              });
            }
          };
          altaEnsayo(){
            if(this.ensayo.idEnsayo){
              const key$=this.ensayo.idEnsayo
              this.ensayo = this.formularioEnsayo.value;
              this.ensayo.idEnsayo=key$;
              this.ensayoService.change(this.ensayo,this.ensayo.idEnsayo).subscribe(data=>{
                this.router.navigate(['/ensayo','lista']);
              })
            }else{
              const data:Ensayo = this.formularioEnsayo.value;
              this.ensayoService.new(data).subscribe(data=>{
                this.router.navigate(['/ensayo','lista']);
              });
            }

          }
          bajaEnsayo(){
            this.ensayoService.delete(this.ensayo.idEnsayo).subscribe(data=>{
              this.router.navigate(['/ensayo','lista',{onSameUrlNavigation:'reload'}]);
            });
          }

        }
```

If we need to see the template I leave the github links:

[Father Page](https://github.com/JuanKitu/ProyectoGIS/blob/master/client/src/app/pages/lista-ensayos/lista-ensayos.page.html)

[Children Page](https://github.com/JuanKitu/ProyectoGIS/blob/master/client/src/app/pages/lista-ensayos/ensayo.page.html)

[Form Component](https://github.com/JuanKitu/ProyectoGIS/blob/master/client/src/app/components/formulario-ensayo/formulario-ensayo.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

To ask Angular to detecet changes you can use `ChangeDetectorRef`

Import it

`import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';`

Inject it

```js
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { 
}
```

And use it where you need

```js
this.cd.markForCheck();
this.cd.detectChanges();
```

You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)